# Powershell to test website page availability & HTTP response code status try/catch

Tags: powershell

I am trying to modify the code below so it can test the website page under the main web page:

```
Clear-Host
$serverName = 'hotel.com/login', 'bing.com/help', 'yahoo.com/mail', 'bong.com', 'bing.com', 'hotel.com'
$statusCodesAllowed = (200, 302, 401) #Update this array to include the HTTP status codes that you want to mark as OK.$stat = 0

Foreach ($URL in $serverName) {
    Try {
        $web = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://$URL -Method Head -UseDefaultCredentials -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction Stop
        $stat = [int]($statusCodesAllowed -contains $web.statusCode)
        Write-Host "`nURL: $($URL) - $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($URL))" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        Write-Host 'Statistic.Status: '$stat -ForegroundColor Green
        Write-Host 'Message.Status: ' $web.StatusCode $web.StatusDescription -ForegroundColor Green
    }

    Catch {
        $statusCode = ($_.Exception.Message.Substring(($_.Exception.Message.IndexOf('(') + 1), 3))
        $stat = [int]($statusCodesAllowed -contains $statusCode)
        Write-Host "`nURL: $($URL) - $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($URL))" -ForegroundColor Red
        Write-Warning 'Statistic.Status: '$stat
        Write-Warning 'Message.Status: '$_.Exception.Message
    }
}

Finally { Remove-Variable serverName, statusCodesAllowed, stat, web, statusCode -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
```

The code above is working fine for the main page, but not with the further **main.website/pagename** format.

Error:

```
Exception calling "GetHostAddresses" with "1" argument(s): "No such host is known"
At line:17 char:40
+ ...  "`nURL: $($URL) - $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($URL))" -Fore ...
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SocketException
 
Exception calling "GetHostAddresses" with "1" argument(s): "No such host is known"
At line:17 char:40
+ ...  "`nURL: $($URL) - $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($URL))" -Fore ...
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SocketException
 
Exception calling "GetHostAddresses" with "1" argument(s): "No such host is known"
At line:17 char:40
+ ...  "`nURL: $($URL) - $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses($URL))" -Fore ...
+                          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SocketException
```

Lastly, how can I filter out the error message when the webpage cannot be accessed or host is not reachable? So the error can be friendlier like:

1. URL cannot be found
2. The host cannot be reached.

Comment: You may need to use the host+domain portion of the URI. `($url -split '/')[0]` should work

Comment: @AdminOfThings, thank you for the suggestion of the code, however, when I modify it into: $web = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri https://($url -split '/')[0] -Method Head -UseDefaultCredentials -UseBasicParsing -ErrorAction Stop
It is not working for all Server address & URL input?

Comment: Only do that for the dns resolution part.

Answer (score 1):

The `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses` method expects a hostname or IP address as an argument. Including the URL in the argument will throw an error. An easy way to yield consistent results with your data set is to split the hostname and domain from the URL:

```
Write-Host "`nURL: $(($URL -split '/')[0]) - $([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostAddresses(($URL -split '/')[0]))"
```

Comment: Is still got the error like below: when checking for hotel.com/login page.
URL: hotel.com - 204.74.99.101
Write-Warning : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '0'.
At line:18 char:9
+         Write-Warning 'Statistic.Status: '$stat
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Write-Warning], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteWarningCommand.